# weird behavior with redirecting if the user is not logged-in

Tags: php, javascript

I have a two `setInterval(myFunction,40000)` and  `setInterval(myFunction2,50000)`  where myFunction and myFunction2 are making ajax requests and if the user is not logged-in

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$home.'" />';
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> self.location = "'.$home.'"; </script>';
exit();
```

In the ajax respons there is :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://site.com/login" />
<script type="text/javascript"> self.location = "http://site.com/login"; </script>
```

but the page is not changing and after 6 requests is changing.

The ajax

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"http://site.com/thing.php",
data:submitData,
dataType:"html",
success:function(data){someDiv.html(data);}
});
```

in thing.php

```
<?php

if(is_logged()){
-- the code
} 

else {
 -- the redirect code
}
?>
```

?>

And the code is working but after the 6 request

Comment: Please show us `yourFunction` and `yourFunction2`. Why are you delivering html in the ajax response?

Comment: because i want only user who are logged to use it

Comment: You wrote that already. How do you receive the html in the ajax-script? How and when do you start the ajax request? We need code to help you.

Comment: I bet you have something on the server side which generates a URL. This function probably detects if a user is logged in and, if they're not, always gives the URL of your login page. OK, that much was obvious. So what do you want it to do? Only logged users can use it, right? So then, don't even bother making these requests if the user is not logged.

Answer (score 1):

The meta element won't do anything because meta elements are only allowed in head, not in any div in the body.

The script should execute and redirect you to $home as soon as it is inserted into the document. I can't tell you why it would work only after the sixth request. Why do you send 6 of them at all? Are you getting any errors in your console? Are you sure the script is getting executed properly?

Comment: because this is a script for updating the time of the post and every 50 sec to change it.There is no errors and also have a fav button and again if the user is not logged to redirect him to the main page and is working.

Comment: In the ajax preview i get the html code for redirect but it dosent work.. and after the 6 request is finaly redirecting to the main page.

Comment: And where is the difference? What changes in your DOM, please inspect that. I guess the meta element changes the parsing behaviour. Add an alert to the script. Test. Swap script and meta tag. Test.

Comment: I add above the php code <script>alert(4);</script> but nothing was alerted in google debugging tool in the ajax preview i see the code.And again after 6 request the page is redirecting

Comment: So what does your **DOM** look like after someDiv.html(data)? **Inspect it.** Is the <script>alert(4);</script> really there?

Comment: Please answer my last question.

Comment: Is not since below the html and javascript code there is exit(); so everything below will not work

Comment: So even if I am log-in still i'm redirected to the main page ... and i donw know how this is happening

Comment: Your PHP does not interest me. You have some HTML, building a document, where you start the ajax call. How does the DOM of that document change in the ajax-success function? Use the DOM Inspector of your browser.